# Split list into sublist based on part of value

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
L= ['v1_A', 'v1_B', 'v1_C', 'V2_A', 'V2_B', 'V2000_A']
```

and I want to split it into sublists so all values that contain V1 become one (sub?)list, all values that contain "V2", "V2000", etc.

The length and number of sublist can differ, but all are identified by the part before the underscore.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to *group* your strings by the initial value, you have two options:

1. Use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby); this makes grouping easy provided your data is already sorted on that first value:

   ```
   from itertools import groupby

   grouped = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(L, lambda s: s.partition('_')[0])]
   ```

   The lambda here provides `groupby()` with the value to group on; it'll give you separate generators (assigned to `g` in the above code) that will yield values where the group key doesn't vary. As the lambda produces the first part of each string, that means the input is grouped on your `v1`, `V2`, `V2000`, etc. prefixes.
2. Use a dictionary to group items by the common prefix. Use this if your input is *not* sorted:

   ```
   grouped = {}
   for elem in L:
       key = elem.partition('_')[0]
       grouped.setdefault(key, []).append(elem)
   grouped = grouped.values()
   ```

   If you use Python 3, that last line would be `grouped = list(grouped.values())`

Both produce a nested list for each prefix, grouping all values by that prefix. Both use [`str.partition()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) to split off just the part before the first `_` underscore.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> L= ['v1_A', 'v1_B', 'v1_C', 'V2_A', 'V2_B', 'V2000_A']
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(L, lambda s: s.partition('_')[0])]
[['v1_A', 'v1_B', 'v1_C'], ['V2_A', 'V2_B'], ['V2000_A']]
>>> grouped = {}
>>> for elem in L:
...     key = elem.partition('_')[0]
...     grouped.setdefault(key, []).append(elem)
... 
>>> grouped.values()
[['V2_A', 'V2_B'], ['V2000_A'], ['v1_A', 'v1_B', 'v1_C']]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick replies. My data is presorted so the Itertools.groupby works. I really need to learn about all the elements  in the code (and stop being afraid of Lambda's).

Comment: Weird.. It works when i manualy define the list in Idle, but when I want to use it on real data (in SPSS) i get the error: "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"

Comment: @user3910001: did you use the name `list` in your code perhaps? In that case you have masked the built-in type and the `list(g)` call fails.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I checked my script, closed and reopend my file and all, but didn't completely restart SPSS. Turns out Python has a better memory than I do and remembers my previous script. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
L= ['v1_A', 'v1_B', 'v1_C', 'V2_A', 'V2_B', 'V2000_A']
new_L = []
for i in L:
    new_item = i.split('_')
    new_L.append(new_item)
print new_L

Output: [['v1', 'A'], ['v1', 'B'], ['v1', 'C'], ['V2', 'A'], ['V2', 'B'], ['V2000', 'A']]
```

Hope this gives you the desired result.

Comment: I think the OP wants to *group* the output on the first part.

Answer (score 1):

dictionary is the best option when you want to split and group

```
L= ['v1_A', 'v1_B', 'v1_C', 'V2_A', 'V2_B', 'V2000_A']
new_L = {}
for i in L:
    new_item = i.split('_')
    if new_item[0] in new_L:
        new_L[new_item[0]].append(i)
    else:
        new_L[new_item[0]] = []
        new_L[new_item[0]].append(i)
print new_L
```

the output is

```
{'v1': ['v1_A', 'v1_B', 'v1_C'], 'V2': ['V2_A', 'V2_B'], 'V2000': ['V2000_A']}
```

anyway i agree with @sesha

Answer (score 1):

I seem to be reaching for `itertools.groupby()` more and more these days.

```
from itertools import groupby

def keyfunc(item):
    return item.split('_')[0]

L= ['v1_A', 'v1_B', 'v1_C', 'V2_A', 'V2_B', 'V2000_A']

grouped_list = [list(v) for k,v in groupby(sorted(L), keyfunc)]

>>> grouped_list
[['V2000_A'], ['V2_A', 'V2_B'], ['v1_A', 'v1_B', 'v1_C']]
```

Another way is to use a `collections.defaultdict`. A defaultdict of lists provides a clean way to create lists in dictionaries :

```
from collections import defaultdict

L= ['v1_A', 'v1_B', 'v1_C', 'V2_A', 'V2_B', 'V2000_A']
d = defaultdict(list)
for s in L:
    d[s.split('_')[0]].append(s)

grouped_list = d.values()

>>> grouped_list
[['v1_A', 'v1_B', 'v1_C'], ['V2_A', 'V2_B'], ['V2000_A']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L= ['v1_A', 'v1_B', 'v1_C', 'V2_A', 'V2_B', 'V2000_A']
print [s.split('_') for s in L]
```

Result:

```
[['v1', 'A'], ['v1', 'B'], ['v1', 'C'], ['V2', 'A'], ['V2', 'B'], ['V2000', 'A']]
```

Or if it's not what you are lookin for:

```
d = {}
for s in L:
    key, value = s.split('_')
    l = d.get(key, [])
    l.append(value)
    d[key] = l
```

Result:

```
>>> d
{'v1': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'V2': ['A', 'B'], 'V2000': ['A']}
>>> d.values()
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'], ['A']]
```

Answer (score 0):

For extracting just one sublist:

```
L= ['v1_A', 'v1_B', 'v1_C', 'V2_A', 'V2_B', 'V2000_A']
sublist = []
for item in L:
    if item[:2] == 'v1': B.append(item)
print sublist
```